# C++ std::this_thread::get_id() passing to cout

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

When using `std::this_thread::get_id()` on CodeBlocks using the c++11 compiler, the thread numbers start from 2. Every time I run the code bellow it prints threads 2 - 6 instead of 0 - 4. Why?

Could it be possible that some other c++ application that is running in the background is using up thread IDs 1 and 2? What sorcery is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

std::mutex m;

class TClass
{
    public:
        void run()
        {
            m.lock();
            cout << "Hello, I'm thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
            m.unlock();
        }
};

int main()
{
    TClass tc;
    std::thread t[5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        t[i] = std::thread(&TClass::run, &tc);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        t[i].join();
    }
    cout << "All threads terminated." << endl;
}
```

Comment: your main runs in the first thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no guarantee about the values returned by [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id). You cannot assume that the value will begin from zero or will be sequential. That is **unspecified**.